# How to call Azure AD Graph API in case of web application that uses WS-Federation to sign-in users from a single Azure Active Directory tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect, azure-ad-graph-api, ws-federation

Based on the code sample mentioned at URL: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-wsfederation , I implemented an application that uses WS-Federation (ASP.Net WS-Federation OWIN middleware) to authenticate users from an Azure AD tenant. Now I am looking for an approach to query the Graph API later in my application to fetch additional claims information required from application point of view.

Here in this scenario, I would like to know whether it is possible to query the Graph API or not. Do I need to update the existing WS-Federation protocol to OpenId Connect.

Can anyone help me to provide their guidance here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideal would be to move to OpenId Connect, which would allow you to take care of both sign in and API in a single setup and flow.
If you want to stick with your current ws-fed setup, you can layer oauth2 on top of your implementation and retrieve the access token you need any time after the sign in. We have a sample showing exactly that, see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-oauth2-useridentity/

Comment: Thanks a lot Vittorio for your response. It helps me a lot :)

Comment: The link is not working and unfortunately, I have to stick with the current implementation using the ws-federation. Can I find it somewhere?